# What is the difference between CKEDITOR.document and CKEDITOR.dom.document?

Tags: javascript, dom, ckeditor

In the ck-editor documentation CkEDITOR.dom.document is defined as -

```
Represents a DOM document.
```

and example is given as -

```
var document = new CKEDITOR.dom.document( document )
```

what should be the parameter 'document' to this function?

Also in CKEDITOR core codebase this definition is given -

```
CKEDITOR.document = new CKEDITOR.dom.document( document );
```

which says that CKEDITOR.document is the document of the window containing the CKEDITOR instance.One can fetch anything from window's DOM for example -

```
alert( CKEDITOR.document.getBody().getName() ); // 'body'
```

I am getting confused between the significance of the two and how to use them differently,where to use them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### `CKEDITOR.document`

As you noticed `CKEDITOR.document` is defined as follows

```
CKEDITOR.document = new CKEDITOR.dom.document( document );
```

Which means it's a **topmost** `document` for CKEditor library. This is the **document where the library is included and loaded**. Usually, it's also the topmost document of the web page

```
window.document === CKEDITOR.document.$ // true
```

`CKEDITOR.document` is also a common document for all CKEditor [inline instances](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline). So if you create a number of them like

```
var i1 = CKEDITOR.inline( 'inline1' );
var i2 = CKEDITOR.inline( 'inline2' );
```

you'll notice that all of them share the same document

```
i1.document.equals( CKEDITOR.document ); // true
i2.document.equals( CKEDITOR.document ); // true
```

because WYSIWYG editing goes directly in [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) elements within `CKEDITOR.document`.

### `CKEDITOR.document` and `editor.document`

On the other hand, there could be many sub–documents in a web page i.e. because **each `<iframe>` means new `window` and `window.document`**. And this is exactly what happens when you create a [classic editor instance](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_framed) which brings a new `<iframe>` with [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) body for editing (yes, you are editing text within and `<iframe>`, not `<textarea>`).

You may notice that each instance has own separate `document` ([`CKEDITOR.editor-property-document`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-property-document)) and those documents have noting to do with `CKEDITOR.document`.

```
var c1 = CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea1' );
var c2 = CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea2' );

c1.document.equals( CKEDITOR.document ); // false
c2.document.equals( CKEDITOR.document ); // false
c1.document.equals( c2.document ); // false
```

Each instance calls `new CKEDITOR.dom.document( documentWithinAnIframe )` and assigns it to `editor.document`.

### Conclusions

So to sum up

- [`CKEDITOR.document`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-property-document) is a topmost `document` where CKEditor library is included and loaded.
- [`editor.document`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-property-document) is a document associated with editor instance. All [inline instances](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline) share the same document (`CKEDITOR.document`) while all [classic instances](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_framed) have their own documents.
- [`CKEDITOR.dom.document`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.document) is a constructor of CKEditor library that wraps the native DOM document into [`CKEDITOR.dom.domObject`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.domObject), exposing nice API to the users (like [`equals()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.domObject-method-equals) method) for manipulation in the code.

  - It's an analogue of [`CKEDITOR.dom.element`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element) but for documents instead of elements.
  - Both `CKEDITOR.document` and `editor.document` are instances of `CKEDITOR.dom.document`.

Comment: Ok I am now getting in details what each element of CKEDITOR signify.Just one question though - How can I make CKEDITOR.dom.element object in the jquery object?

Comment: What I mean by above statement is this - by using  dialog.getContentElement().getElement() APIs I am able to get instance of CKEDITOR.dom.element and I can use methods like getId to get it's native DOM ID. But how to convert it into jquery object so that I call advanced jquery methods to it? Again thanks.

Comment: `dialog.getContentElement().getElement().$` should give you a native DOM object. `$( dialog.getContentElement().getElement().$ )` should return jQuery object.